# Can't delete multiple rows of data between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to delete data from a SQL Server database with this query:

```
DELETE FROM [ONEDB].[dbo].[Invoice]
WHERE [DateUploaded] BETWEEN '2011-11-14' AND '2014-01-01'
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AuditRecord, Line 36
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error?

Comment: Probably on a faulty trigger on that table

Comment: How would I fix that??

Comment: How could I know without seeing the code of the trigger?

Comment: You need to look at the code for AuditRecord.

Comment: OK. Here is a better question. How do I find the code of the trigger.

Comment: If you are using SSMS, then go to the table, click in the `+` sign to expand it, then go to triggers

Comment: If I commented this trigger out and then execute my query. Would that do any harm to the table at all??

Comment: Again, how could I know without knowing what that trigger is supposed to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6pcdk1mh/ - Here is the code to the trigger.

Comment: That trigger is a complete mess. It assumes only one row is ever updated or deleted at a time from your table

Comment: Right. So now that you've seen the trigger. Would it damage the table if I commented it out.

Comment: No, that trigger is to have an audit table that stores the changes that are made on the `Invoice` table. If you disable the trigger, then you won't be saving your changes in your audit table

Comment: Well I'm planning on deleting records from the audit table as well.

Comment: Then what's the point on having an audit table in the first place?

Comment: Don't know I didn't build the database, just maintaining it. So if I deleted a record of the Invoice table. It should delete off the Audit table as well then.

Comment: The trigger is copying a 'doomed' record into the AuditTable immediately before it gets deleted from Invoice. It's badly written, as Lamak says, so you can only delete one record at a time as it stands. You need to discuss with the business/data owner about what to do. The AuditTable is probably there for good reason.